# Input JSON type data to Laravel 5.2

Tags: json, laravel-5

I have file txt (data.txt) with this value :

```
{"id":"1","title":"first Testing","completed":"Yes"}

{"id":"2","title":"Second Testing","completed":"no"}

{"id":"3","title":"Third Testing","completed":"no"}
```

and table Data with field `id`, `title`, and `completed`..

how I can input all value in data.txt into my Table (Data) with laravel 5.2??

Thanks before.. and sorry for my bad english..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read file and convert it to **PHP Array**

```
 $arrays = json_decode(file_get_contents('data.txt'), true);
```

Then with simple foreach

```
foreach($arrays as $array) {
   $myObject = new Model();
   $myObject->id = $array['id'];
   $myObject->title = $array['title'];
   $myObject->completed = $array['completed'];
   $myObject->save();
}
```

Or you could do it **straightfoward** if you defined `$fillable` attributes

```
foreach($arrays as $array)
   Model::create($array);
```

[Eloquent: Mass Assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#mass-assignment)

Using **Query Builder**

```
DB::table('data')->insert($arrays);
```

[Query Builder: Insert](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#inserts)

Answer (score 0):

Seeing you `data.txt` example it seems like the value is not well formatted JSON. To handle this kind of value first you need to `explode` your data with `\n` as delimeter. Then filter it to get rid all empty elements, after that map each item using `json_decode`, this should be worked:

```
$data = file_get_contents('path/to/data.txt');
$data = array_filter(explode("\n", $data));
$data = array_map(function ($item) {
    return json_decode($item, true);
}, $data);

// Insert to your database table
DB::table('mytable')->insert($data);
```

If you `data.txt` contains well formatted JSON then you can skip the exploding, filtering and mapping steps:

```
$data = file_get_contents('path/to/data.txt');

// Insert to your database table
DB::table('mytable')->insert($data);
```

If you are about to do it more than once, it's recommended to use eloquent model `updateOrCreate()` method to prevent duplicated rows. Here is example:

```
// Uses $data value from the first example
foreach($data as $row) {
    MyModel::updateOrCreate(['id' => $row['id'], $row);
}
```

Just an addition in case you want to go with Laravel's way (Filesystem). Put your `data.txt` in `storage/app` folder then use `Storage` facade to retrieve the data.

```
$data = Storage::get('data.txt');
$data = array_filter(explode("\n", $data));
$data = array_map(function ($item) {
    return json_decode($item, true);
}, $data);

DB::table('mytable')->insert($data);

// Or

foreach($data as $row) {
    MyModel::updateOrCreate(['id' => $row['id'], $row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these codes

in laravel you could use filesystem to get the file. but here is the basic version. Hope this will help.

```
$file = fopen("data.txt","r");

while(! feof($file))
  {
    $data = json_decode(fgets($file), true);

    //write your code to Store your data

  }

fclose($file);
```